# How to count valid and invalid lines in file

Tags: java, validation, unit-testing, if-statement, count

I have the following code:

```
public class generator {


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("results.txt"));// creates a scanner to
                                                        // scan from a file
    String line;
    String HomeTeam, AwayTeam;
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        line = s.nextLine(); // reads the next line from the file
        line = line.trim(); // trims the line
        String[] elements = line.split(":"); // splits the line
        if (elements.length == 4) {
            HomeTeam = elements[0].trim(); // trims home team
            AwayTeam = elements[1].trim(); // trims away team
            elements[2] = elements[2].trim();
            elements[3] = elements[3].trim();

            if (HomeTeam.length() != 0 && AwayTeam.length() != 0) { // check if position is present
                try {   // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with "exceptions"

                    int HomeScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[2]);  // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                    int AwayScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[3]);
                    System.out.println(HomeTeam + " ["+ HomeScore +"]" + " | " + AwayTeam + " ["+AwayScore+"]");
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Now my question is: how do I count the valid and invalid lines as well as total number of score in entire file?

Sample input file is:
Leeds United : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Chelsea :  Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa : Middlesbrough : 3 : 1
Tottenham Hotspur : Stoke City : 0 : 0
West Ham United : Wigan Athletic :2 : 1
Fulham : Liverpool : 1 : 2
Wigan Athletic : Leeds United : 2 : 2
Arsenal Liverpool :2:2
Hull City: Tottenham Hotspur : 3 : 5
Everton : Portsmouth:4 : 2
Stoke City : West Bromwich Albion : 5 : 4
Leeds United : Liverpool : 1: 10
Blackburn Rovers : Fulham : 1 : 1
West Ham United : Newcastle United : 0 : 0
Manchester United : Wigan Athletic : 1 : 2
Hull City : Sunderland : 2 : 3
Chelsea : Manchester City :1
Fulham : Leeds United : 1 : 2
Wigan Athletic : Tottenham Hotspur : 2 : 2
Hull City : Everton : 3 : 5
: :2:0
Sunderland : Blackburn Rovers : 4 : 2
Stoke City : West Bromwich Albion : 5 : 4
Hull : Liverpool : 5: x
Blackburn Rovers : Fulham : 1 : 1
Chelsea  : Everton : a : 1
Sunderland : Newcastle United : 0 : 0
Hull : :2:3
Sunderland : Blackburn Rovers : 1 : 2
Hull City : Everton : 2 : 3
Leeds United : Chelsea : 1 : 2
Chelsea : Manchester City : 1 : 1
Aston Villa:Fulham:3:1
Manchester City : Stoke City : 0 : 0
West Ham United : Middlesbrough : 2 : 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You check validity so what's the problem with counting? Create two variables: `ValidNumb` and `InvalidNumb`. Increase `ValidNumb` after `System.out.println()`. Increase `InvalidNumb` if `elements.length` not equal 4, lenght of team names equal 0 or You catch exception during conversions scores to integers.
To count all scores: create one more variable `allScores` and add them to `HomeScore` and `AwayScore` in `try` block.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("results.txt"));// creates a scanner to
                                                    // scan from a file
    String line;
    String HomeTeam, AwayTeam;
    Int ValidNumb = 0, InvalidNumb = 0; //counters of valid and invalid lines
    Int AllScores = 0; //sum of all goals
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        line = s.nextLine(); // reads the next line from the file
        line = line.trim(); // trims the line
        String[] elements = line.split(":"); // splits the line
        if (elements.length == 4) {
            HomeTeam = elements[0].trim(); // trims home team
            AwayTeam = elements[1].trim(); // trims away team
            elements[2] = elements[2].trim();
            elements[3] = elements[3].trim();

            if (HomeTeam.length() != 0 && AwayTeam.length() != 0) { // check if position is present
                try {   // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with "exceptions"

                    int HomeScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[2]);  // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                    int AwayScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[3]);
                    AllScores = AllScores + HomeScore + AwayScore; //sum up scores
                    System.out.println(HomeTeam + " ["+ HomeScore +"]" + " | " + AwayTeam + " ["+AwayScore+"]");
                    ValidNumb++; //line is valid
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    InvalidNumb++; //scores are not integers
                }

            }
            else {InvalidNumb++;} //HomeTeam or AwayTeam are empty

        }
        else {InvalidNumb++;} //not enough elements in line

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what I was looking for :) Can you by any chance help me with one more thing which is basically counting all the goals in valid lines and adding them together? I would really appreciate it :) once again many thanks

Comment: I've edited my post and add a line to sum up all the goals. Enjoy! (and don't forget to vote up post if You'd appreciate it ;) )

Answer (score 0):

So you would need counter variables for every metrics that you need.So before your while loop define them as:

```
int totalAwayScore = 0, totalHomeScore = 0, invalidLines = 0, totalLines = 0;
```

Within while loop, increment `totalLines` as

```
totalLines++;
```

which means you have next line to read. Your try catch is where you know how much is score so keep on adding to metrics that you defined above like:

```
try {   // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with "exceptions"
  int HomeScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[2]);  // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
  int AwayScore = Integer.parseInt(elements[3]);
  totalAwayScore += AwayScore;
  totalHomeScore += HomeScore;
  System.out.println(HomeTeam + " ["+ HomeScore +"]" + " | " + AwayTeam + " ["+AwayScore+"]");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    invalidLines++;
}
```

Here if you get number format exception, you get to know that it's invalid line and hence increment the value of variable that holds invalid lines in a file.

At the end of the while loop you print the stats like:

```
System.out.println("Total home score is " + totalHomeScore + " totalAway score is " + totalAwayScore + " invalid lines were " + invalidLines + " of total " + totalLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood but:

1. you need to increment a counter of invalid lines in the catch
   section. It indicates that the line is wrong because the number is
   not a number;
2. you need to increment a counter of invalid lines in an else section
   of the if

   `if (elements.length == 4)`

   it means that you have too much or too many arguments;
3. you need to increment a counter of invalid lines if HomeTeam and
   AwayTeam are =="" because you don't have the name of the team;

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add two counters - one for all (*allCounter*) and one for wrong lines (*wrongCounter*):

- at the beginning of every loop iteration increment *allCounter*:

> ```
> while (s.hasNext()) {
>     allCounter++;
>     line = s.nextLine(); // reads the next line from the file
>     ...
> ```

- if something is *wrong*, increment *wrongCounter* and continue to next iteration of loop

> ```
> if (elements.length != 4) {
>     ++wrongCounter;
>     continue; //breaks this iteration and moves to next one
> }
> //otherwise proceed normally
> homeTeam = elements[0].trim(); // trims home team  
> awayTeam = elements[1].trim(); // trims away team
> ...
> ```

Similarly in second *if* and *catch* clause:

> ```
>  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
>      ++wrongCounter;
>  }
> ```

And of course:

> ```
>  int correctCounter = allCounter - wrongCounter;
> ```

One more thing: By Java convention you should **write all variable/method names with *camelCase***, i.e start with small letter and then start every new word with capital letter:
Example: not *HomeTeam*, but *homeTeam*